# How to access request object in @MessageMapping method with spring websocket implementation

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-websocket

I am integrating an existing spring MVC web application with spring websockets. I was successfully able to integrate by following the instructions in

https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/

The existing web application has a filter, which sets a few of the attributes. I have a requirement to access the attributes set by the filter in the controller i,e in @MessageMapping method.

Could some one tel how can we access the request object in the @MessageMapping method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When a STOMP client connects to the application, it first has to request a protocol upgrade to switch to websocket. Once using that websocket connection, the messages sent/received don't go through your regular Servlet filter - only the first HTTP request (the "Handshake") did.

Depending on your use case, there are several ways to achieve this.

If it's related to Authentication, then [there are existing features for this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-stomp-authentication) in the Spring Framework, but also in Spring Security.

If it's related to the HTTP session, you can easily ask for all HTTP session attributes to be copied into the websocket session - or even customize the Handshake for your own needs ([see reference doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-server-handshake)). Once done, you can inject the Websocket scope in a `@MessageMapping` controller method and get those attributes ([see reference doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-stomp-websocket-scope)).

Comment: Thanks for explanation, I did exactly similar by introducing a custom interceptor but how to access a session (say websocket session ojbect ) in the controller?

Comment: that's already in the answer: the websocket scope. You can access session attributes in message headers. http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-stomp-websocket-scope

Comment: Thank you @Brian Cloze . In the similar lines of interceptors , is there a way to intercept a destroy or logout websocket connection, so that I can reset my session parameters?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm getting your last comment, but spring-session http://projects.spring.io/spring-session/ offers ways to keep alive an HTTP session while the client sends messages over websocket.

Comment: @pavan you can do that using a `@EventListener`  with `SessionDisconnectEvent` parameter